# Cannot display label for multiple checkboxes in Rails 4.2 and Bootstrap 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason the following code will not show the correct labels ('Credit Card', 'Paypal', 'Direct Deposit'):

```
= form_for @merchant, layout: :horizontal do |f|
  = f.check_box :payment_accepted, { :multiple => true }, 'Credit Card', nil
  = f.check_box :payment_accepted, { :multiple => true }, 'Paypal', nil
  = f.check_box :payment_accepted, { :multiple => true }, 'Direct Deposit', nil
  = f.submit 'Save Changes', :class => 'btn btn-primary'
```

It will show 'Payment accepted' as labels for all 3 checkboxes

Wrapping a checkbox within a label in a block:

```
= f.label :payment_accepted, 'Credit Card' do
  = f.check_box :payment_accepted, { :multiple => true }, 'Credit Card', nil
```

Has no effect.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try adding another argument before the multiple block `= f.check_box :payment_accepted, "type", { :multiple => true }, 'Credit Card', nil`

Comment: What do you want the check box values to be, 'Credit Card', etc?

Comment: Yes. This is the admin interface that will determine which payment methods a given merchant accepts.

Comment: Adding another argument before the multiple block as per toddmetheny's suggestion throws an invalid number of arguments error: _wrong number of arguments (5 for 1..4)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this out, and it turned out to be obvious. Here's the thing:

When using the Rails form Helpers and Bootstrap, the f.checkbox helper will generate a label by default. There is no way to override this behaviour other than subclassing the form helper function (overkill?)

So adding an f.label will only duplicate the labels and has no effect on the label generated by the f.checkbox helper.

The solution is to customize the actual label the f.checkbox helper function generates, since it turns out it takes a (seemingly undocumented) :label parameter in the options group.

So this finally did the trick:

```
=f.check_box :payment_accepted, { :multiple => true, :label => 'Credit Card'}, 'Credit Card', nil
```

Hopes it saves someone hours of pulling out their hair (like me).

Answer (score 2):

It is actually a common misconception that you need to use the label method for form checkboxes. You should be able to use the default bootstrap syntax.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example

```
  .checkbox
    %label
      = f.check_box :payment_accepted, { :multiple => true }, 'Credit Card', nil
      Credit Card
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had already tried that and using your exact code my checkbox shows 2 labels: 'Payment accepted' AND 'Credit Card' one under the other. Both labels are clickable and will toggle the checkbox value. This is the generated HTML code: <div class='checkbox'> <label> <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9"><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Credit Card" name="merchant[payment_accepted][]" id="merchant_payment_accepted_credit_card" /> Payment accepted</label></div></div></div> Credit Card </label> </div>